# Why my button is below "Workflow" in my navbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am working with tailwind and responsive design. Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Transition } from "@headlessui/react";

function Nav() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="bg-gray-800">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div className="flex">
              <div>
                <img className="h-8 w-32" alt="Workflow" />
              </div>
              <div className="hidden md:block ml-auto">
                <div className="space-x-4">
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className=" hover:bg-gray-700 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Dashboard
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Team
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Projects
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Calendar
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Reports
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
              <button
                onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
                type="button"
                className="bg-gray-900 inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
                aria-controls="mobile-menu"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                {!isOpen ? (
                  <svg
                    className="block h-6 w-6"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                    />
                  </svg>
                ) : (
                  <svg
                    className="block h-6 w-6"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                    />
                  </svg>
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Transition
          show={isOpen}
          enter="transition ease-out duration-100 transform"
          enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
          enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leave="transition ease-in duration-75 transform"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
        >
          {(ref) => (
            <div className="md:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
              <div ref={ref} className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="hover:bg-gray-700 text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Dashboard
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Team
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Projects
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Calendar
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Reports
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </Transition>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

but the problem is when I reduce the width of the window I got that :

[image: What I got]

The problem is that I would like to have the button at the right.

How can I do that ?

I precise I want to keep the others menus like that :

[image: others menus]

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

[full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-uhf16?file=/src/components/Navbar.js:0-5337)

Comment: you can add `display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse` to the button and workflows parent to flip them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try move this code:

```
<div className="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
          <button
            onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
            type="button"
            className="bg-gray-900 inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
            aria-controls="mobile-menu"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
            {!isOpen ? (
              <svg
                className="block h-6 w-6"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                />
              </svg>
            ) : (
              <svg
                className="block h-6 w-6"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                />
              </svg>
            )}
          </button>
        </div>
```

To inside of before div

```
<div className="flex">
```

And add the next code div to before of first div mentioned (after move it):

```
<div className="m-auto md:hidden"></div>
```

Change the class of first div mentioned for this:

```
<div className="flex md:hidden">
```

And that is all. So the final code is this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Transition } from "@headlessui/react";

function Nav() {
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
return (
<div>
  <nav className="bg-gray-800">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className="flex">
          <div>
            <img className="h-8 w-32" alt="Workflow" />
          </div>
          <div className="hidden md:block ml-auto">
            <div className="space-x-4">
              <a
                href="#"
                className=" hover:bg-gray-700 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
              >
                Dashboard
              </a>

              <a
                href="#"
                className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
              >
                Team
              </a>

              <a
                href="#"
                className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
              >
                Projects
              </a>

              <a
                href="#"
                className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
              >
                Calendar
              </a>

              <a
                href="#"
                className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
              >
                Reports
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="m-auto md:hidden"></div>
          <div className="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
          <button
            onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
            type="button"
            className="bg-gray-900 inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
            aria-controls="mobile-menu"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
            {!isOpen ? (
              <svg
                className="block h-6 w-6"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                />
              </svg>
            ) : (
              <svg
                className="block h-6 w-6"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                />
              </svg>
            )}
          </button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <Transition
      show={isOpen}
      enter="transition ease-out duration-100 transform"
      enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
      enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
      leave="transition ease-in duration-75 transform"
      leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
      leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
    >
      {(ref) => (
        <div className="md:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
          <div ref={ref} className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
            <a
              href="#"
              className="hover:bg-gray-700 text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
            >
              Dashboard
            </a>

            <a
              href="#"
              className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
            >
              Team
            </a>

            <a
              href="#"
              className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
            >
              Projects
            </a>

            <a
              href="#"
              className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
            >
              Calendar
            </a>

            <a
              href="#"
              className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
            >
              Reports
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </Transition>
  </nav>
</div>
);
}

export default Nav;
```

You can see the result [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-f02n7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FNavbar.js&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

please insert this line :)

```
return (
    <div>
      <nav className="bg-gray-800">
        <div>
          <div className="flex flex-row justify-between">  <==== "this"
            <div className="flex">
              <div>
                <img className="w-32 h-8" alt="Workflow" />
              </div>
```

also check more document in [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-direction#class-reference),
Happy coding!